# CSS Customizations for certain page

Tags: customization, css, conditional-tags

I've been using Wordpress for a while, and came to a point where I need to make css customizations, but only for a certain page. I know that one way to do this is to use conditional tags:

`if ( is_page( 'mypage' )`

And that's where I get stuck!

Are there any other ways of making css customizations, only for a certain page?

Comment: `conditional tags to edit css` — that's not very clear. But you can have a CSS file load only on a specific page, if that's what you want

Comment: does your theme use `body_class()` in the body tag (in header.php ?) ?

Comment: Any progress on this (or your other) question(s)?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of rules that you need to conditionally apply (there's no hard and fast rule, but, to make one up, maybe 10-15+ lines?) then @aahan's answer is the way to go. If you only have a few though, just work off body class.

In your `header.php` file (that's the common name at least) make sure the `<body>` has:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Then you'll get lots of classes you can use to write conditional styles like

```
.page-123 .entry-content
.template-my-custom-template-php h1
```

etc...

Answer (score 3):

You'd need something like this (to be added in functions.php):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse57014_register_script');
function wpse57014_register_script(){

    //Register and enqueue stylesheet only on this page
    if ( is_page( 'mypage' ) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'wpse57014_mypage_stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri().'/mypage-style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse57014_mypage_stylesheet' );
    }

}
```

Where `mypage` is the slug of the page on which ONLY you want to load the stylesheet. Replace instances of `mypage` in the code to keep the code understandable to you (or modify it as you wish, if you know what you are doing).

`get_template_directory_uri().'/mypage-style.css'` is the path to the stylesheet in your theme, for example — `http://example.com/wp-content/themes/MY THEME/mypage-style.css`.